# Error during installation Saleor using Docker Step 3/21 : COPY requirements_dev.txt /app/

Tags: docker, saleor

I'm trying to install and run Saleor in my mac using Docker.
I followed the steps in the saleor's installation page and GitHub.
https://github.com/mirumee/saleor-platform

First I got the error :  "ERROR: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.dev" when I
`run docker-compose build` 
I solved it by adding the following code to the docker-compose.yml:

```
    build:
      context: ./saleor
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
```

It worked for many steps, then, I got the error:
**ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: {'status': 'Downloading', 'progressDetail': {'current': 9406944, 'total': 9996337}, 'progress': '[===============================================>   ]  9.407MB/9.996MB', 'id': 'edaf0a6b092f'}**.

As well, when running
`docker-compose run --rm api python3 manage.py collectstatic --noinput` 
I get the error:

**Step 3/21 : COPY requirements_dev.txt /app/
ERROR: Service 'api' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder866326918/requirements_dev.txt: no such file or directory**.

anyone could help me please ?